# How to make a transition between two states in animator controller in different layers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Base Layer:

[image: Base Layer]

and the PickupAnimation layer:

[image: PickupAnimation layer]

I want to make a transition from the base layer grounded state to the pickupanimation layer PickupAnimation state and also to make that the state in the PickupAnimation layer will not start automatic by default.

Should I use Blend Tree for that? or maybe there is no really need for two layers?

This is the script I want to use with the new layer:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cube;
    public Transform destinationTransform;
    public float distance;
    public Animator animator;

    private bool startChild = false;
    private float timer;
    private bool hasPickedUp = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        timer = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (animator != null && !hasPickedUp)
        {
            distance = Vector3.Distance(cube.position, destinationTransform.position);
            float dot = Vector3.Dot(destinationTransform.position, cube.forward);

            if (distance < 0.5f && dot < 0)
            {
                hasPickedUp = true;
                animator.SetTrigger("PickupTrigger");
            }

            if (startChild)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                cube.position = Vector3.Lerp(cube.position, destinationTransform.position, timer);

                if (timer >= 1.0f)
                {
                    cube.parent = destinationTransform;
                    cube.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    startChild = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void PickupEvent()
    {
        hasPickedUp = false;
        startChild = true;
    }

    private void OnAnimatorIK(int layerIndex)
    {
        if (animator != null)
        {
            // Check if the Pickup animation layer is active (layerIndex is the layer index of your Pickup animation layer)
            if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(layerIndex).IsName("PickupAnimation"))
            {
                // Calculate the IK position for the right hand (Assuming it's the hand that interacts with the cube)
                Vector3 cubePosition = cube.position;
                animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, cubePosition);

                // Adjust the IK position for the right hand (fine-tune the position if needed)
                Vector3 offset = Vector3.up * 0.2f; // Example: You can add an offset to the Y-axis to match the hand position
                animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, cubePosition + offset);

                // Enable IK for the right hand
                animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 1f);
            }
            else
            {
                // Disable IK for the right hand if the Pickup animation is not active
                animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 0f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```